# Computing a limit involving the product

Tags: calculus, limits, infinite-product

$$\left[\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{(k+1)^{n}}{n^{n+1}}\right)\right)\right]1$$

The answer of this question is 0. But my answer is e. Here is my approach.
​
We can simplify the product inside the limit using the following properties of limits:

The product of limits is equal to the limit of the product (if the individual limits exist).
The limit of a sum is equal to the sum of the limits (if the individual limits exist).
Applying these properties, we can rewrite the product inside the limit as:

\begin{gathered} \rm\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(1+\frac{2^n}{n^{n+1}}\right)\left(1+\frac{3^n}{n^{n+1}}\right)\cdots\left(1+\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}\right) \\ \end{gathered}

We can then take the natural logarithm of both sides and use the properties of logarithms to simplify the expression further:

\begin{gathered}\rm\ln\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(1+\frac{2^n}{n^{n+1}}\right)\left(1+\frac{3^n}{n^{n+1}}\right)\cdots\left(1+\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}\right)\right) \\ \end{gathered}

\begin{gathered} \rm=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \ln\left(\left(1+\frac{2^n}{n^{n+1}}\right)\left(1+\frac{3^n}{n^{n+1}}\right)\cdots\left(1+\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}\right)\right) \\ \end{gathered}

\begin{gathered} \rm=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(\ln\left(1+\frac{2^n}{n^{n+1}}\right)+\ln\left(1+\frac{3^n}{n^{n+1}}\right)+\cdots+\ln\left(1+\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}\right)\right) \\ \end{gathered}
​

We can then use the property that for small values of x, ln(1+x) is approximately equal to x, to approximate each term in the sum:

\begin{gathered} \rm\ln\left(1+\frac{k^n}{n^{n+1}}\right) \approx \frac{k^n}{n^{n+1}} \\ \end{gathered}
​

​

Using this approximation, we get:

\begin{gathered} \rm\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(\frac{2^n}{n^{n+1}}+\frac{3^n}{n^{n+1}}+\cdots+\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}\right) \\ \end{gathered}

We can then use the fact that the largest term in the sum dominates as n goes to infinity, to approximate the sum with the last term:

\begin{gathered} \rm lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n = e \\ \end{gathered}

Therefore, the final answer is:

\begin{gathered} \rm \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{(k+1)^{n}}{n^{n+1}}\right)\right) = e.\\\end{gathered}

Comment: What is the $1$ in red? $$\left[\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{(k+1)^{n}}{n^{n+1}}\right)\right)\right]\color{red}{1}$$

Comment: Your limit bears a striking resemblance to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4417359/why-is-lim-limits-n-to-infty-prod-limits-k-1n-left1-frack1n2)

Comment: Do you have a citation for "The product of limits is equal to the limit of the product (if the individual limits exist). The limit of a sum is equal to the sum of the limits (if the individual limits exist)."?  I find this suspicious in an infinite product.

Comment: A product of numbers greater than $1$ will always be greater than $1$, so the limit can't be $0$.

Comment: The limit of the largest term is equal $0.$ You have missed the factor $n$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$0<\ln\left (1+{k^n\over n^{n+1}}\right )\le {k^n\over n^{n+1}}\quad (*)$$
Next for a fixed $k\le n$ we have
$$2^n+3^n+\ldots +(n+1-k)^n+(n+2-k)^n\ldots +(n+1)^n\\
\le n(n+1-k)^n+k(n+1)^n$$
Hence
$${2^n+3^n+\ldots +(n+1)^n\over n^{n+1}}\le {(n+1-k)^n\over n^n}+{k\over n}{(n+1)^n\over n^n} \\
=\left (1-{k-1\over n}\right )^n+{k\over n}\left (1+{1\over n}\right )^n$$ We obtain
$$\limsup_n {2^n+3^n+\ldots +(n+1)^n\over n^{n+1}}\le e^{1-k}$$ As $k$ is arbitrary, we get
$$\lim_n {2^n+3^n+\ldots +(n+1)^n\over n^{n+1}}=0$$
By $(*)$ we get
$$\lim_n \ln\left [\prod_{k=1}^n \left (1+{k^n\over n^{n+1}}\right )\right ]=\lim_n \sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left (1+{k^n\over n^{n+1}}\right ) =0$$
Therefore the limit of the product is equal $1.$

Answer (score 3):

Another approach, we have that

$$\log \left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{k^{n}}{n^{n+1}}\right)\right)= \sum_{k=1}^{n}\log \left(1+\frac{k^{n}}{n^{n+1}}\right)\le\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^{n}}{n^{n+1}}\to 0$$

indeed

$$k^n \le \frac{(k+1)^{n+1}-k^{n+1}}{n+1} \implies \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^{n}}{n^{n+1}}\le\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)n^{n+1}}=\frac1n\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n \to 0\cdot e =0$$

Comment: ${1\over n+1}+O({1\over n})=O({1\over n})$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Yes of course! My idea was to mantain the form $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^{p}}{n^{n+1}}=\frac1{p+1}+O\left(\frac1n\right)$. Do you think that in this way is not clear or confusing?

Comment: You get the asymptotic formula for fixed $p.$ It does not necessarily imply the same formula for $p=n.$ For example $${p\over n}=O({1\over n})$$ but ${n\over n}\neq O({1\over n}).$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Ok, I get your point now. Let me check it better! Thanks

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I've revised by another approch, I hope this one now is good! Thanks

Comment: Nice! Simpler than mine (+)